# Cannot send email using stmp Python in docker container, how to fix?

Tags: python, docker

Cannot send email in docker container on remote server, I can send email with the same code on my pc, and it works, but on remote server does not work, even if just create a script, it's just stuck without error

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders


def send_yandex_email(credentials: dict, file_path: str, file_name: str):
    try:
        mail_content = credentials["email_content"]
        sender_address = credentials["sender_address"]
        sender_pass = credentials["sender_pass"]
        receiver_address = credentials["receiver_address"]
        #Setup the MIME
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['From'] = sender_address
        message['To'] = receiver_address
        message['Subject'] = credentials["email_subject"]
        #The subject line
        message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'html'))
        with open(file_path, "rb") as attachment:
            payload = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            payload.set_payload(attachment.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(payload) #encode the attachment
            payload.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
            message.attach(payload)

        session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com', 465)
        session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
        text = message.as_string()
        session.sendmail(sender_address, credentials['receiver_address'].split(','), text)
        session.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        return e

send_yandex_email(_INVOICE_CREDENTIALS,'./zczx.jpg', 'zczx');
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.9.5

COPY ./gmcrm /app/src
COPY ./ssl /app/ssl
COPY ./poetry.lock /app
COPY ./pyproject.toml /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi
RUN pip3 install gunicorn uvloop httptools

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app/src

ENV ACCESS_LOG=${ACCESS_LOG:-/proc/1/fd/1}
ENV ERROR_LOG=${ERROR_LOG:-/proc/1/fd/2}

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/gunicorn \
    -b 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    -w 4 \
    -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app \
    --keyfile=/app/ssl/example.kz.key \
    --certfile=/app/ssl/example.crt \
    --chdir /app/src \
    --access-logfile "$ACCESS_LOG" \
    --error-logfile "$ERROR_LOG"
```

DockerCompose

```
services:
    gmcrm:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./gmcrm:/app/src
        environment:
          - PORT=8080
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        networks:
            - gmcrm_network
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-Nginx
        depends_on:
            - gmcrm
        networks:
            - gmcrm_network
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443

networks:
    gmcrm_network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: "it [is] just stuck without error": you capture *all* exceptions, and then return those, but never print the return value. Why not simply let any exception be uncaught and bubble up: then you get to see the error and might have a better idea of what's going on. That is the whole point of errors. Catching every error is just bad.

Comment: @9769953 i try a lot, and just paste this variant of code

Comment: Impossible to answer - you have not show the dockerfile, or how you are running the container. Can the remote server even contact the smtp server?

Comment: @SiHa sory for that, add

Comment: docker-compose up -d

Comment: Did you try a variant *without* catching any exception? Did that result in no output or error messages?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the bare minimum. The Python script doesn't (likely) need an attachment part to have the same problem, and the container is running gunicorn, which is irrelevant here: try reproducing the problem with just running the Python script sending a simple email from a container.

Comment: @9769953 yes sir i try, even on server it just stuck

Comment: @9769953 i try on just servedr, and inside docker, both just stuck

Comment: you state *remote server* but what exactly is this *remote server*? A lot of cloud computing services block email by default to prevent spam coming from their servers, which could put their IPs on SPAM lists...

Comment: @EdoAkse sir, linode.com, ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linode blocks outgoing mail by default. Refer to their [docs here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/running-a-mail-server/)

Always refer to the documentation of the provider of your cloud based server if you encounter SMTP issues.